# Evaluate $f(\pi^2)$, $f(-\pi^2)$

Tags: calculus, functions

Let the function $f(x)$ be defined by $f(x)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(2n+1)!}x^n$. Evaluate $f(\pi^2)$ and $f(-\pi^2)$.

For this question, all I have to do is substitute these $\pi^2$ and $-\pi^2$ as x and evaluate. If I did my calculations correctly then $f(-\pi^2)= 2- \frac{e^{\pi}-e^{-\pi}}{2\pi}$. Can someone check this answer?

I also can't find $f(\pi^2)$, but a friend of mine has told me that it is equal to $0$. Not so sure about that. The way I got my answer was through term by term integration, if this is important.

Comment: How did you manage to obtain this value ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

You have for $x>0$
$$
f\left(x\right)=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{\left(2n+1\right)!}\left(\sqrt{x}\right)^{2n+1}=-\frac{\sin\left(\sqrt{x}\right)}{\sqrt{x}}
$$
and for $x<0$, you'll have
$$
f\left(x\right)=-\frac{\sinh\left(\sqrt{x}\right)}{\sqrt{x}}
$$

Comment: Thank you. So for $\pi^2$ I can substitute the equation for $x>0$ and vice versa for $-\pi^2$?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $x>0$, we can manipulate the given series as follows:

$$\begin{align*}f(x)&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^n}{(2n+1)!}=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x^n}{(2n+1)!} \\ &=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{\left(\sqrt{x}\right)^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{\left(\sqrt{x}\right)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} \\ &=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\sin\left(\sqrt{x}\right).\end{align*}$$

For the case $x<0$: you can substitute $y=-x$, where $y>0$, and then manipulate similarly.